# Tensor Flow Error: required broadcastable shapes when training Variable Auto Encoder for Text Posts

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, lstm, autoencoder

Good morning,

I'm attempting apply and adapt a variational auto encoder that I found [here](https://github.com/NicGian/text_VAE/blob/master/text_VAE_v18.ipynb) to a dataset consisting of news headlines. The data will feed into the neural network, but the neural network will not train. I believe the error has to do with the way the loss function is written, but I cannot figure it out. My full repository is available [here](https://github.com/PaulKMandal/News-Headline-GAN/blob/main/VAE1.ipynb)

```
#Much thanks to NicGian for his VAE code!
#NicGian's Repo can be found here https://github.com/NicGian/text_VAE/blob/master/text_VAE_v18.ipynb
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import Bidirectional, Dense, Embedding, Input, Lambda, LSTM, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed, Layer, Activation, Dropout
#from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.layers import ELU
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Model
from scipy import spatial
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import codecs
import csv
import os

from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import disable_eager_execution
disable_eager_execution()

max_len = 20
batch_size = 100
emb_dim = EMBEDDING_DIM
latent_dim = 32
intermediate_dim = 16
epsilon_std = 1.0
kl_weight = 0.01
num_sampled=500
act = ELU()


x = Input(shape=(max_len,))
#x = tf.random.normal(shape=(max_len,))
x_embed = Embedding(NB_WORDS, emb_dim, weights=[glove_embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=max_len, trainable=False)(x)
h = Bidirectional(LSTM(intermediate_dim, return_sequences=False, recurrent_dropout=0.2), merge_mode='concat')(x_embed)
#h = Bidirectional(LSTM(intermediate_dim, return_sequences=False), merge_mode='concat')(h)
#h = Dropout(0.2)(h)
#h = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='linear')(h)
#h = act(h)
#h = Dropout(0.2)(h)
z_mean = Dense(latent_dim)(h)
z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim)(h)

def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_var = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch_size, latent_dim), mean=0.,
                              stddev=epsilon_std)
    return z_mean + K.exp(z_log_var / 2) * epsilon

# note that "output_shape" isn't necessary with the TensorFlow backend
z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,))([z_mean, z_log_var])
# we instantiate these layers separately so as to reuse them later
repeated_context = RepeatVector(max_len)
decoder_h = LSTM(intermediate_dim, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.2)
decoder_mean = Dense(NB_WORDS, activation='linear')#softmax is applied in the seq2seqloss by tf #TimeDistributed()
h_decoded = decoder_h(repeated_context(z))
x_decoded_mean = decoder_mean(h_decoded)


# placeholder loss
def zero_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.zeros_like(y_pred)

# Custom loss layer
class CustomVariationalLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.is_placeholder = True
        super(CustomVariationalLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.target_weights = tf.constant(np.ones((batch_size, max_len)), tf.float32)

    def vae_loss(self, x, x_decoded_mean):
        #xent_loss = K.sum(metrics.categorical_crossentropy(x, x_decoded_mean), axis=-1)
        labels = tf.cast(x, tf.int32)
        xent_loss = K.sum(tfa.seq2seq.sequence_loss(x_decoded_mean, labels, 
                                                     weights=self.target_weights,
                                                     average_across_timesteps=False,
                                                     average_across_batch=False), axis=-1)#,
                                                     #softmax_loss_function=softmax_loss_f), axis=-1)#,
        kl_loss = - 0.5 * K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)
        xent_loss = K.mean(xent_loss)
        kl_loss = K.mean(kl_loss)
        return K.mean(xent_loss + kl_weight * kl_loss)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = inputs[0]
        x_decoded_mean = inputs[1]
        print(x.shape, x_decoded_mean.shape)
        loss = self.vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean)
        self.add_loss(loss, inputs=inputs)
        # we don't use this output, but it has to have the correct shape:
        return K.ones_like(x)
    
def kl_loss(x, x_decoded_mean):
    kl_loss = - 0.5 * K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)
    kl_loss = kl_weight * kl_loss
    return kl_loss

loss_layer = CustomVariationalLayer()([x, x_decoded_mean])
vae = Model(x, [loss_layer])
opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.01) 
vae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=[zero_loss], metrics=[kl_loss])
vae.summary()
```

This code then gives the following output:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm_2 will not use cuDNN kernels since it doesn't meet the criteria. It will use a generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU.
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm_2 will not use cuDNN kernels since it doesn't meet the criteria. It will use a generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU.
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm_2 will not use cuDNN kernels since it doesn't meet the criteria. It will use a generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU.
WARNING:tensorflow:Layer lstm_3 will not use cuDNN kernels since it doesn't meet the criteria. It will use a generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU.
(None, 20) (100, 20, 10000)
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_2 (InputLayer)           [(None, 20)]         0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 embedding_1 (Embedding)        (None, 20, 100)      1000000     ['input_2[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 bidirectional_1 (Bidirectional  (None, 32)          14976       ['embedding_1[0][0]']            
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 dense_3 (Dense)                (None, 32)           1056        ['bidirectional_1[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 dense_4 (Dense)                (None, 32)           1056        ['bidirectional_1[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 lambda_1 (Lambda)              (100, 32)            0           ['dense_3[0][0]',                
                                                                  'dense_4[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 repeat_vector_1 (RepeatVector)  (100, 20, 32)       0           ['lambda_1[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 lstm_3 (LSTM)                  (100, 20, 16)        3136        ['repeat_vector_1[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 dense_5 (Dense)                (100, 20, 10000)     170000      ['lstm_3[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 custom_variational_layer_1 (Cu  (None, 20)          0           ['input_2[0][0]',                
 stomVariationalLayer)                                            'dense_5[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,190,224
Trainable params: 190,224
Non-trainable params: 1,000,000
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

When I attempt to train the model, I use the following code:

```
def create_model_checkpoint(dir, model_name):
    filepath = dir + '/' + model_name + ".h5" 
    directory = os.path.dirname(filepath)
    try:
        os.stat(directory)
    except:
        os.mkdir(directory)
    checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=filepath, verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
    return checkpointer

checkpointer = create_model_checkpoint('models', 'vae_seq2seq_test_very_high_std')



vae.fit(x_partial_train, x_partial_train,
     shuffle=True,
     epochs=100,
     batch_size=batch_size,
     validation_data=(x_val, x_val), callbacks=[checkpointer])

#print(K.eval(vae.optimizer.lr))
#K.set_value(vae.optimizer.lr, 0.01)

vae.save('models/vae_lstm.h5')
#vae.load_weights('models/vae_seq2seq_test.h5')
```

And get the following error:

```
Train on 11985 samples, validate on 1500 samples
Epoch 1/100
11800/11985 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - kl_loss: nan

2022-07-28 11:01:06.923587: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1733] INVALID_ARGUMENT: required broadcastable shapes

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [27], in <cell line: 15>()
      9     return checkpointer
     11 checkpointer = create_model_checkpoint('models', 'vae_seq2seq_test_very_high_std')
---> 15 vae.fit(x_partial_train, x_partial_train,
     16      shuffle=True,
     17      epochs=100,
     18      batch_size=batch_size,
     19      validation_data=(x_val, x_val), callbacks=[checkpointer])
     21 #print(K.eval(vae.optimizer.lr))
     22 #K.set_value(vae.optimizer.lr, 0.01)
     24 vae.save('models/vae_lstm.h5')

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training_v1.py:776, in Model.fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    773 self._check_call_args('fit')
    775 func = self._select_training_loop(x)
--> 776 return func.fit(
    777     self,
    778     x=x,
    779     y=y,
    780     batch_size=batch_size,
    781     epochs=epochs,
    782     verbose=verbose,
    783     callbacks=callbacks,
    784     validation_split=validation_split,
    785     validation_data=validation_data,
    786     shuffle=shuffle,
    787     class_weight=class_weight,
    788     sample_weight=sample_weight,
    789     initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
    790     steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    791     validation_steps=validation_steps,
    792     validation_freq=validation_freq,
    793     max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    794     workers=workers,
    795     use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays_v1.py:641, in ArrayLikeTrainingLoop.fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    637     raise ValueError('`validation_steps` should not be specified if '
    638                      '`validation_data` is None.')
    639   val_x, val_y, val_sample_weights = None, None, None
--> 641 return fit_loop(
    642     model,
    643     inputs=x,
    644     targets=y,
    645     sample_weights=sample_weights,
    646     batch_size=batch_size,
    647     epochs=epochs,
    648     verbose=verbose,
    649     callbacks=callbacks,
    650     val_inputs=val_x,
    651     val_targets=val_y,
    652     val_sample_weights=val_sample_weights,
    653     shuffle=shuffle,
    654     initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
    655     steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    656     validation_steps=validation_steps,
    657     validation_freq=validation_freq,
    658     steps_name='steps_per_epoch')

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays_v1.py:377, in model_iteration(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_inputs, val_targets, val_sample_weights, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, mode, validation_in_fit, prepared_feed_values_from_dataset, steps_name, **kwargs)
    374 callbacks._call_batch_hook(mode, 'begin', batch_index, batch_logs)
    376 # Get outputs.
--> 377 batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
    378 if not isinstance(batch_outs, list):
    379   batch_outs = [batch_outs]

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/backend.py:4284, in GraphExecutionFunction.__call__(self, inputs)
   4278 if (self._callable_fn is None or feed_arrays != self._feed_arrays or
   4279     symbol_vals != self._symbol_vals or
   4280     feed_symbols != self._feed_symbols or self.fetches != self._fetches or
   4281     session != self._session):
   4282   self._make_callable(feed_arrays, feed_symbols, symbol_vals, session)
-> 4284 fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals,
   4285                             run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   4286 self._call_fetch_callbacks(fetched[-len(self._fetches):])
   4287 output_structure = tf.nest.pack_sequence_as(
   4288     self._outputs_structure,
   4289     fetched[:len(self.outputs)],
   4290     expand_composites=True)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py:1480, in BaseSession._Callable.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1478 try:
   1479   run_metadata_ptr = tf_session.TF_NewBuffer() if run_metadata else None
-> 1480   ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,
   1481                                          self._handle, args,
   1482                                          run_metadata_ptr)
   1483   if run_metadata:
   1484     proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT: required broadcastable shapes
     [[{{node lambda_1/mul}}]]
     [[metrics_2/kl_loss/Identity/_267]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT: required broadcastable shapes
     [[{{node lambda_1/mul}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

I'm honestly at a loss here and have been trying to fix this for the past week, so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: with _variable auto encoder_ you probably mean _variational auto encoder_ right?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Yes I did, my bad!

Comment: also, you are trying to use variational autoencoder on sequences?...

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia That is correct.